# Subtract SQL queries with count and group by

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries and I need to subtract the results of the column "antal" from the first one with the second query.

The first query looks like this:

```
SELECT A402.Objgrpben, A402.Objgrupp, A402.FärgObjektgrupp, COUNT(A806.Aordernr) AS Antal
FROM A806 INNER JOIN
    A406 ON A806.Ställeid = A406.Ställeid INNER JOIN
    A400 ON A806.Objektid = A400.Objektid INNER JOIN
    A402 ON A400.ObjGrupp = A402.Objgrupp INNER JOIN
    Cams_Global.dbo.A957 ON A806.LevId = Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevId INNER JOIN
    Cams_Global.dbo.A960 ON A406.OmrådesNr = Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr
WHERE (Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr IN (1031, 1046, 1032)) AND (A406.Kund = 5566321537) AND 
    (A806.Beställning = 0) AND (A400.ObjGrupp IN (1161, 1000, 100, 10, 40, 1157, 50, 60, 20, 70)) AND 
                         (Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevIdGrupp IN (1001, 1000)) AND (A806.ProtokollSparad = 0)
GROUP BY A402.Objgrpben, A402.Objgrupp, A402.FärgObjektgrupp
ORDER BY A402.Objgrpben
```

And the result of the first query:

```
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Objgrpben                      | Objgrupp | FärgObjektgrupp      | Antal |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Badplatser                     | 1161     | #717171              | 7     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Fastighet                      | 1000     |                      | 1     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Fjärrvärme                     | 100      | #974706              | 3     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Gator och Trafik               | 10       | #ff005e              | 8     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Gatubelysning                  | 40       | #FFFF00              | 15    |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Lekplatser                     | 1157     | #00939c              | 17    |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Park o Grönområden             | 50       | #008124              | 1     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Renhållning                    | 60       | #ff00e4              | 4     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Vatten och Avlopp              | 20       | #0701ff              | 1     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Vinterväghållning              | 70       | #00ffe4              | 2     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
```

The second query looks like this:

```
SELECT A402.Objgrpben, A402.Objgrupp, A402.FärgObjektgrupp, COUNT(A806.Aordernr) AS Antal
FROM A806 INNER JOIN
    A406 ON A806.Ställeid = A406.Ställeid INNER JOIN
    A400 ON A806.Objektid = A400.Objektid INNER JOIN
    A402 ON A400.ObjGrupp = A402.Objgrupp INNER JOIN
    Cams_Global.dbo.A957 ON A806.LevId = Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevId INNER JOIN
    Cams_Global.dbo.A960 ON A406.OmrådesNr = Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr
WHERE (Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr IN (1031, 1046)) AND (A406.Kund = 5566321537) AND 
    (A806.Beställning = 0) AND (A400.ObjGrupp IN (1161, 1000, 100, 10, 40, 1157, 50, 60, 20, 70)) AND 
                         (Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevIdGrupp IN (1001, 1000)) AND (A806.ProtokollSparad = 0)
GROUP BY A402.Objgrpben, A402.Objgrupp, A402.FärgObjektgrupp
ORDER BY A402.Objgrpben,
```

And the the result of the second query:

```
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Objgrpben                      | Objgrupp | FärgObjektgrupp      | Antal |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Badplatser                     | 1161     | #717171              | 7     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Fastighet                      | 1000     |                      | 1     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Fjärrvärme                     | 100      | #974706              | 2     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Gator och Trafik               | 10       | #ff005e              | 3     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Gatubelysning                  | 40       | #FFFF00              | 1     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Lekplatser                     | 1157     | #00939c              | 4     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Park o Grönområden             | 50       | #008124              | 1     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
```

The result I am after is:

```
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Objgrpben                      | Objgrupp | FärgObjektgrupp      | Antal |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Badplatser                     | 1161     | #717171              | 0     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Fastighet                      | 1000     |                      | 0     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Fjärrvärme                     | 100      | #974706              | 1     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Gator och Trafik               | 10       | #ff005e              | 5     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Gatubelysning                  | 40       | #FFFF00              | 14    |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Lekplatser                     | 1157     | #00939c              | 13    |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Park o Grönområden             | 50       | #008124              | 0     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Renhållning                    | 60       | #ff00e4              | 4     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Vatten och Avlopp              | 20       | #0701ff              | 1     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| Vinterväghållning              | 70       | #00ffe4              | 2     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------------------+-------+
```

I want to keep the row even if the sum is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.Objgrpben,
       t.Objgrupp,
       t.FärgObjektgrupp,
       SUM(t.Antal) AS Antal
  FROM (SELECT A402.Objgrpben,
               A402.Objgrupp,
               A402.FärgObjektgrupp,
               COUNT(A806.Aordernr) AS Antal FROM A806
        INNER JOIN A406
          ON A806.Ställeid = A406.Ställeid
        INNER JOIN A400
          ON A806.Objektid = A400.Objektid
        INNER JOIN A402
          ON A400.ObjGrupp = A402.Objgrupp
        INNER JOIN Cams_Global.dbo.A957
          ON A806.LevId = Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevId
        INNER JOIN Cams_Global.dbo.A960
          ON A406.OmrådesNr = Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr WHERE (Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr IN (1031, 1046, 1032))
         AND (A406.Kund = 5566321537)
         AND (A806.Beställning = 0)
         AND (A400.ObjGrupp IN (1161, 1000, 100, 10, 40, 1157, 50, 60, 20, 70))
         AND (Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevIdGrupp IN (1001, 1000))
         AND (A806.ProtokollSparad = 0)
       GROUP BY A402.Objgrpben,
                A402.Objgrupp,
                A402.FärgObjektgrupp

      UNION ALL

      SELECT A402.Objgrpben,
             A402.Objgrupp,
             A402.FärgObjektgrupp,
             -1 * COUNT(A806.Aordernr) AS Antal FROM A806
        INNER JOIN A406
          ON A806.Ställeid = A406.Ställeid
        INNER JOIN A400
          ON A806.Objektid = A400.Objektid
        INNER JOIN A402
          ON A400.ObjGrupp = A402.Objgrupp
        INNER JOIN Cams_Global.dbo.A957
          ON A806.LevId = Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevId
        INNER JOIN Cams_Global.dbo.A960
          ON A406.OmrådesNr = Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr WHERE (Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr IN (1031, 1046))
         AND (A406.Kund = 5566321537)
         AND (A806.Beställning = 0)
         AND (A400.ObjGrupp IN (1161, 1000, 100, 10, 40, 1157, 50, 60, 20, 70))
         AND (Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevIdGrupp IN (1001, 1000))
         AND (A806.ProtokollSparad = 0)
       GROUP BY A402.Objgrpben,
                A402.Objgrupp,
                A402.FärgObjektgrupp) t
GROUP BY t.Objgrpben,
         t.Objgrupp,
         t.FärgObjektgrupp
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! could you explain what  - (1 * COUNT(A806_1.Aordernr)) does? is that what make the subtraction?

Comment: You want to subtract one field at two queries. I thought sum with negative is a type of subtracting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT s1.Objgrpben, sq1.Objgrupp, sq1.FärgObjektgrupp, sq1.Antal-sq2.Antal 
FROM (SELECT A402.Objgrpben, A402.Objgrupp, A402.FärgObjektgrupp, COUNT(A806.Aordernr) AS Antal
        FROM A806 INNER JOIN
            A406 ON A806.Ställeid = A406.Ställeid INNER JOIN
            A400 ON A806.Objektid = A400.Objektid INNER JOIN
            A402 ON A400.ObjGrupp = A402.Objgrupp INNER JOIN
            Cams_Global.dbo.A957 ON A806.LevId = Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevId INNER JOIN
            Cams_Global.dbo.A960 ON A406.OmrådesNr = Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr
        WHERE (Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr IN (1031, 1046, 1032)) AND (A406.Kund = 5566321537) AND 
            (A806.Beställning = 0) AND (A400.ObjGrupp IN (1161, 1000, 100, 10, 40, 1157, 50, 60, 20, 70)) AND 
                                 (Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevIdGrupp IN (1001, 1000)) AND (A806.ProtokollSparad = 0)
        GROUP BY A402.Objgrpben, A402.Objgrupp, A402.FärgObjektgrupp
        ORDER BY A402.Objgrpben) sq1
join (SELECT A402.Objgrpben, A402.Objgrupp, A402.FärgObjektgrupp, COUNT(A806.Aordernr) AS Antal
        FROM A806 INNER JOIN
            A406 ON A806.Ställeid = A406.Ställeid INNER JOIN
            A400 ON A806.Objektid = A400.Objektid INNER JOIN
            A402 ON A400.ObjGrupp = A402.Objgrupp INNER JOIN
            Cams_Global.dbo.A957 ON A806.LevId = Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevId INNER JOIN
            Cams_Global.dbo.A960 ON A406.OmrådesNr = Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr
        WHERE (Cams_Global.dbo.A960.OmrådesNr IN (1031, 1046)) AND (A406.Kund = 5566321537) AND 
            (A806.Beställning = 0) AND (A400.ObjGrupp IN (1161, 1000, 100, 10, 40, 1157, 50, 60, 20, 70)) AND 
                                 (Cams_Global.dbo.A957.LevIdGrupp IN (1001, 1000)) AND (A806.ProtokollSparad = 0)
        GROUP BY A402.Objgrpben, A402.Objgrupp, A402.FärgObjektgrupp
        ORDER BY A402.Objgrpben,) sq2 on sq2.Objgrpben = sq1.Objgrpben
```

Note: It is not a good practice use spaces and special characters in column names